# How to convert a excel file to base64 and then convert base64 back to excel in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, postgresql, base64

How to convert a excel file to base64 and then convert base64 back to excel in python?
I intent to store the Base64 data in a database and retrieve it on demand and convert back to excel? Any help?

Comment: I think you will struggle to only do this in memory. .. I suspect the easiest path to success is to save the excel file to disk, then convert the file to base64 and save in your db ... when getting it out , decode it , write to a temp file and then read in the temp file ... it might make more sense to just save the file on disk and include a pointer to the file in your database

Comment: Hey Joran, I can't store it in local, but how can one encode a file in base64 and then decode? Could you provide me an example in python?

Comment: `base64.b64encode(open("some.xlsx","rb").read())` ... I dont understand how you cannot save it locally ... but thats fine i dont necesarrily need to

Comment: This looks good, also I am writing an automation script , so can't store anything on local : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import base64

def open_target_file(target_path):
    with open(target_path,"rb") as excel_file:
        return excel_file.read()

def encode_file(excel_file):
    return base64.b64encode(excel_file)

def decode_file():
    return base64.b64decode(excel_file)

your_excel_path = ""
destiny_path = ""

excel_file = open_target_file()
encoded_excel = encode_file(excel_file)
decoded_excel = decode_file(encoded_excel)

with open(destiny_path, "wb") as decoded_file:
    decoded_file.write(decoded_excel)
```

Somthing like this should work.

Comment: Hi Joao , this might help, when i decode the excel file it will still be in string, how should I convert it back to excel?

Comment: If store the file like binarie in your base and after decode the same binarie file you will not have any problems !

Comment: nice answer :) that should do it all ... but you will need to change your file paths to something other than "" I think ... you *might* be able to use stringIO to avoid writing to disk all together... maybe...big maybe